# jmp short 0x0 causing loop forever

Tags: buffer-overflow

I am told that the instruction "jmp short 0x0" which translates to the object code '\xeb\xfe' causes a process to loop forever. How exactly does this work?

Comment: I'd imagine that `0x0` here is the relative offset +0 with respect to the program counter.  However, in some instruction sets (e.g. 68k), the offset is with respect to somewhere in the middle of the instruction rather than the beginning, meaning you would have to jump to offset -2 or similar to get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instruction will elicit a jump back to itself.  `\xeb\xfe` translates literally to "Jump ahead -2 bytes from the start of the next instruction."  Since this instruction is itself 2 bytes long, the jump destination will be the jump instruction itself.