# understanding executing c code in stack ( Mac Hackers Handbook code)

Tags: c, stack, shellcode

I was looking at this example w.r.t executing code in the stack:

```
#include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  char shellcode[] = “\xeb\xfe”;
  int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
          void (*f)();
          char x[4];
          memcpy(x, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode));
          f = (void (*)()) x;
          f();
}
```

This causes a segmentation fault. My understanding this is because the shellcode runs out of memory for the rest of the bytes as x only has a size of 4 bytes. And this results in creating a write operation of copying to stack memory and that causes a seg. fault as stack memory is read only.
Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Stack is not read only, but it is most likely not executable.

Comment: And there are only 3 bytes to copy. A `\x` means the next two characters indicate the hexadecimal value of the byte which is actually put in the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisely what OS are you running this on?

To quote from the Mac Hacker's Handbook:

> Leopard does not set the XD bit on any parts of memory besides the
>   stack. **It is unclear if this is a bug, an oversight, or intentional,**
>   but even if the software's memory permissions are set to be
>   nonexecutable, you can still execute anywhere except the stack. The
>   following simple program illustrates that point.
>
> [ your snippet follows ]

(Emphasis mine.)

The code should segfault if permissions are set to nonexecutable (or if permissions are omitted altogether). It didn't on Leopard, which even the author questions. What you observed is perfectly normal behavior for a modern OS.

I would add: Try running it through a debugger. `\xeb\xfe` is an infinite loop but you technically shouldn't even loop once. The OS should slap you on the wrist (which is apparently happening here).

Comment: Got it. Did not realized that \xeb\xfe is an infinite loop. I am testing this on Lion. So basically since the function never return's the stack would never return and this would kinda freeze the system...is that the point here ?

Comment: @ZionKing processes run independently so it won't freeze the system.

Comment: This also helps:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609745/jmp-short-0x0-causing-loop-forever

Comment: Hmm..not sure i understand the point of the code and the point the author was trying to make....

Comment: Got it finally after some more thinking. :) Thanks for all the help.